# Begin and Max values configurables (TypoScript - CONTENT)

Tags: typoscript

I'm doing a kind of paginator in TS...
I'm doing a select, but I need to confugre (from a GP:var) the begin (to set the "begin" page) value... But I dont find a way to do that...

I have been looking for it in Google, and everybody says it is a int+calc object... But I dont understand the idea of being a int+calc if I cant set a variable in the calc...

I let you an example of my code

```
10.select {
    pidInList.insertData = 1
    pidInList = this
    max = 5
    begin = 0    #Here is where I would like to configure the begin dynamicaly with stdWrap or something like that
    orderBy = pages_smc_news.date DESC
    leftjoin = pages_smc_news ON(pages_smc_news.pid = pages.uid) LEFT JOIN tt_content ON (tt_content.pid = pages.uid)
    selectFields = pages_smc_news.date, title, bodytext, header,tt_content.pid
    where = header="teaser"
    andWhere = tt_content.sys_language_uid = 0
}
10.renderObj = COA
10.renderObj {
    ...
}
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TYPO3 4.5.x (maybe even in earlier versions) you can use `markers` property of the **[select](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/5/#id2620981)**. This lets you define markers (e.g. ###some_marker###) that you can use in other `select` properties.

```
10.select {
    pidInList.insertData = 1
    pidInList = this
    max = 5
    begin = ###begin###
    orderBy = pages_smc_news.date DESC
    leftjoin = pages_smc_news ON(pages_smc_news.pid = pages.uid) LEFT JOIN tt_content ON (tt_content.pid = pages.uid)
    selectFields = pages_smc_news.date, title, bodytext, header,tt_content.pid
    where = header="teaser"
    andWhere = tt_content.sys_language_uid = 0
    markers {
        begin = TEXT
        begin {
            data = GP:var
            intval = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use a register to store and accumulate the begin variable and override it? Each time my code add up the register variable "num" with a 1 which is a kind of t3 cookie variable, it get erased when you load another page.

```
  begin.stdWrap.cObject = COA
  begin.stdWrap.cObject {
       10 = LOAD_REGISTER
       10.num.cObject = TEXT
       10.num.cObject.data = register:num
       10.num.cObject.wrap = |+1
       10.num.prioriCalc = intval
  }
```